# How could I $unwind an array and update it in place

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document has a field `symptoms`, which is an arrays of array.

I want to `$unwind` it and apply `$addToSet` to remove duplicated items ,

Then just update the document. How to do it ?

**Documents**

```
  "symptoms": [
    [
      "A481 ",
      "A48  ",
      "     "
    ],
    [
      "A48177 ",
      "A48  ",
      "     "
    ]
  ]
```

**Expected Output**

```
  "symptoms": 
    [
      "A481 ",
      "A48  ",
      "A48177 ",
      "     "
    ]
```

### Update

Actually my document has hundreds of fields, how to update the `symptoms` in place and without affect other fields value, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) twice the `symptoms` array and use the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) to exclude the `_id` field. You can use the  [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) to write the result in new collection or replace your existing collection.

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$unwind": "$symptoms" }, 
        { "$unwind": "$symptoms" }, 
        { "$group": { 
                        "_id": "$_id", 
                        "symptoms": { "$addToSet": "$symptoms" }
                    }
        }, 
        { "$project": { "_id": 0, "symptoms": 1 }},
        { "$out": "collection" }
    ]
)
```

Now

```js
db.collection.find()
```

Gives you:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("553a244bea67317760a44347"), "symptoms" : [ "A48177 ", "     ", "A48  ", "A481 " ] }
```

Comment: sorry for missing some information in my original question, will it affect other fields on my document ? pls see my update

Comment: @poc Yes it will. So to do this you you will need to include the other fields in your group stage and use projection to reshape your document. Can you edit your post and add the other  fields?

Comment: I can not any more fields on original fields, I just can flatten the field symptoms